# Connecting Visual Studio 2005 to Team Foundation Server 2008

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2005, tfs-2008

As of now we are using vs2005. We are newly setting up TFS 2008. How do I connect TFS 2008 client to vs 2005 without upgrading it to vs2008 in my system? When I installed TFS 2008 client the options are appearing in VS2008 but not in vs2005.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using VS2005 with the Team Explorer client for 2005, talking to a TFS2008 server for a fewe months.  When we upgraded from TFS2005 to 2008, we had no issues with client connectivity at all.  If you are sticking with VS2005, then you should not need to install the 2008 client - just use the 2005 one.

Comment: Hey thanks. I had to install a hotfixn VS80sp1-KB932544-X86-ENU.exe to connect to TFS server 2008 from Team explorer client 2005. Thx for the help. Can u tell how do I accept an answer here?